# Debian で SDL2 を用いたプログラムを実行しても、ウインドウが表示されない

Tags: c++, linux, sdl

## 起こっている問題

SDL2を使いたいと思っているのですが、何故かウィンドウが表示されません。
ログを見る限りではプログラムは一応動いているっぽいです。ただ、ウィンドウが表示されません。
解決法をご存知の方、どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

### ソースコード（main.cpp）

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "SDL2/SDL.h"
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    cout << "Start" << endl;

    const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 800;
    const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600;

    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_AUDIO) < 0) {
        cout << "SDL init failed." << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // initialize screen
    SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("Hello world !!", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);

    if (window == NULL) {
        SDL_Quit();
        return 2;
    }

    SDL_Renderer* renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);
    SDL_Texture* texture = SDL_CreateTexture(renderer, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGBA8888,
        SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STATIC, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);

    if (renderer == NULL) {
        cout << "Could not create renderer" << endl;
        SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
        SDL_Quit();
        return 3;
    }

    if (texture == NULL) {
        cout << "Could not create texture" << endl;
        SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
        SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
        SDL_Quit();
        return 4;
    }

    // prepare memory
    Uint32* buffer = new Uint32[SCREEN_WIDTH * SCREEN_HEIGHT];

    memset(buffer, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH * SCREEN_HEIGHT * sizeof(Uint32));

    // set every 4bytes as color into memory
    for (int i = 0; i < SCREEN_WIDTH * SCREEN_HEIGHT; i++) {
        buffer[i] = 0x008080FF;
    }

    // update screen
    SDL_UpdateTexture(texture, NULL, buffer, SCREEN_WIDTH * sizeof(Uint32));
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, NULL, NULL);
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);

    bool quit = false;
    SDL_Event event;

    while (!quit) {
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
            if (event.type == SDL_QUIT) {
                quit = true;
            };
        }
        cout << "Loop" << endl;
    }

    // finalize screen
    delete[] buffer;
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyTexture(texture);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();

    cout << "End" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

### 実行結果

```
$ g++ -o main main.cpp `sdl2-config --cflags --libs` -lSDL2
$ ./main
Start
Loop
Loop
Loop
Loop
Loop
        //省略
Loop
Loop
Loop
Loop^C  //ctrl + c
Loop
End
```

Comment: Debianで利用しているデスクトップ環境は何でしょう？ (Dockがあるなら その確認で隠れてるウィンドウが見つかるかもしれない)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

解決の手助けをしてくださった皆様、ありがとうございました。
OpenGLで必要なファイルが足りなかったことが原因だったようです。
以下のページで生成してincludeファイルの中身を「/usr/include」に配置することでウィンドウが表示されるようになりました。
https://glad.dav1d.de/

Answer (score 2):

こちらの環境で動かしてみました。ウィンドウは表示されます。
以下のようにディスプレイを指定するとウィンドウが表示されるかもしれません。

```
DISPLAY=:0.0 ./main
```

表示されない場合はX Serverのインストール、環境設定がうまくいっていない可能性があります。

---

X Serverが起動されていない、または、DISPLAYに設定されていない場合はイベントループがまわりませんでした(Loopが表示されない)。

---

oririさんのコメントにあるよう実際はウィンドウが表示されていて隠れているのかもしれません。

次のコマンドを実行するとすべてのウィンドウの情報が表示されます。

```
DISPLAY=:0.0  xwininfo -root -tree
```

※すでに環境変数DISPLAYが設定されている場合は`DISPLAY=:0.0`は不要です。

Comment: 返信が遅くなり申し訳ありません。試してみた所、ウィンドウの生成自体ができていないようなので、また色々試してから再度質問をさせていただこうと思います。ご回答ありがとうございました。