# pygameが実行できないです。

Tags: python, pygame

pip install pythonはやりました。pygameを実行したとき一瞬だけpython launcherが起動してすぐ消えます。なぜですか？

Comment: pygameは SDLライブラリーを利用していて, このような Q＆Aもあったので参考に (原因は, ファイルが足りなかった, ということ) https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/93801/debian-で-sdl2-を用いたプログラムを実行しても-ウインドウが表示されない

Answer (score 0):

スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！
せっかくのご質問ですが、記述された内容では発生している事象とその原因が分かりにくいように感じました。

`pip install pygame`が実行済みということでしょうか？
ソースコード(`.py`拡張子ファイル)に`import pygame`と記述して実行してもゲーム画面が表示されないのでしょうか？
そうではなく、ゲーム画面が表示されて一瞬で消え、python launcherもすぐに消えてしまうのでしょうか？
それともpythonをインストール済みで、どうしたら`pygame`が使えるのか分からないのでしょうか？
中身が空のソースコードをダブルクリックしても黒い画面が一瞬出るだけでしょうか？

もし実際のソースコードがあるならばそれを質問に追記し、実行環境のOS(Windows11)やpythonのバージョン(3.11.0)などを分かる範囲で記載すると的確な回答をもらいやすくなります。
上記の内容が分からなければ、下記のサンプルコードを実行して正常にゲーム画面が表示されるのか、エラーが発生するのかをコメントや質問文に追記してみてください。

**サンプルコード**

```
import pygame
from pygame import locals
import time
import math
import sys

# 画面初期化(ここから下を消すとゲーム画面は表示されずにpython launcherが終了します)
pygame.init()
surface = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 100)) 

# ゲームループ(ここから下を消すとゲーム画面が一瞬表示された後に消えます)
while True:
    surface.fill((0, 0, 0))
    font_size = 10 + int(abs(math.sin(time.time()) * 50))
    font = pygame.font.Font(None, font_size)
    text = font.render("Hello, StackOverflow!!", True, (0, 255, 100))
    surface.blit(text, [0, 0])
    pygame.display.update()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == locals.QUIT:
            pygame.quit() 
            sys.exit()
```